# Excel formula: For each instance of peak/bottom value in column, get range/distance to the second next peak/bottom

Tags: excel

I am looking to solve the following problem in Excel:

```
ID     Value   Distance
1      1       3
2      0       0
3      -1      3
4      1       0
5      0       0
6      -1      0
7      0       0
```

Essential the distance column is what I want. It looks at peak/bottom values(1 and -1), then scrolling down to find the second next peak or bottom and compute the distance. For example, for ID 1, since it is peak, we looking for the second peak/bottom, ID 3 should be skipped since its the first, so we look at ID 4 and get distance = 4-1 = 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following formula:

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,A2:$A$18/ABS(B2:$B$18),3)/ABS(B2)-A2,0)
```

**Explanation:**

`AGGREGATE` function with first two parameters `15`, `6` and last `3` returns the third smallest value in the array `A2:$A$18/ABS(B2:$B$18)` ignoring errors - in the first row after division the array looks like this `[1, #DIV/0!, 3, 4, #DIV/0!, 6, #DIV/0!, ...]` and returns `4`.

Next, this value is divided by the absolute value of column `B` of the current row (if we divide by 0, then we get an error and the `IFERROR` function returns 0).

Then we subtract the value of column `A` of the current row from the obtained result (in the first row `1`) and we get the desired distance - `3`

To get the third and subsequent values, increase the last parameter of the `AGGREGATE` function accordingly.

[image]

Comment: could you explain the logic? and what if i want to modify the formula to get thrid next/fourth next/fifth next..., how do i change it?

Comment: I tried your formula, weird it does not work on google sheet, please see here https://imgur.com/a/bh00IUP

Comment: @domesome This formula works in excel only. You didn't ask for google sheets.

Comment: I see, thank you. Is there a way to modify this to work with google sheet?

Comment: @domesome For GS should work: ```=IFERROR(SMALL(FILTER(A2:$A$18/ABS(B2:$B$18),(A2:$A$18/ABS(B2:$B$18))>0),3)/ABS(B2)-A2,0)```